# How would you decouple a scenario of lessons and students?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic

Assume you are making a software that manages classes and students.

I'd assume you would have an administrator class, lesson class, and student class.

The administrator class can have various functions such as "get the list of all available lessons" or "get the list of all lessons that a student is enrolled in".

Here's the tricky part.

A lesson can have many students while a student can have many lessons.

Here are some implementations I have thought of:

1. Lesson class contains list of students and student class contains list of lessons:

   Pro: Straightforward, Con: Coupled
2. Lesson class contains list of students and in order to do "get all lessons a student is enrolled in" the administrator class would first get all lessons and then filter lessons containing that student.

   Pro: Not coupled, Con: Inefficient computing
3. In the administrator class, have the following fields :

   - `HashMap<Lesson, [Student]>`
   - `HashMap<Student, [Lesson]>`

   Pro: Not coupled, Con: Messy

None of them seem satisfying to me. Can I get some feedback on this dilemma? What is the typically accepted design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have the complete Student object inside Lesson objects and vice versa.

Lesson class contains a Set of studentIds of the subscribed students

Student class contains a Set of lessonIds in which they are subscribed to.

Your Administrator class can use these Ids to map, filter, retrieve lessons, students and their relationships.

Edit:

I have to say, that in a real life scenario where your data would be persisted for example in a relational database, you should have a table *Students*, a table *Lessons* and a table *StudentsLessons* with  *studentId and lessonId as foreign keys*.

Comment: On the surface, this seems most reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it considering the fact that in future I might need to persist them in the DB.

The relationship between student and lesson is **many-to-many** and hence you need to setup bi-directional
 or unidirectional relationship with these two classes.

- `Bi-directional` -  List of lessons in `Student` class and vice versa
- `Unidirectional` - Either list of lessons in `Student` or list of
  students in `Lesson` class

For example sake, I am setting unidirectional relationship

```
class Student {
    private List<Lesson> lessions;
    // other attributes
}

class Lesson {
    // Lesson attributes
}
```

The `Administrator` class you are talking about is actually a good candidate for service class because it's providing services
such as *"get the list of all available lessons"*

For `Lesson` related queries, I'll create `LessonService`

```
class LessonService {

    // Get the list of all available lessons
    List<Lesson> findAllLessons() {...}

    // Get all lessons a student is enrolled in
    List<Lession> findAllLessons(Student student) {...}
}
```

and finally, there would a `repository/dao` layer that will abstract underlying database.

Your repository could be a simple collection based in-memory or represent the actual database.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned bi-directional or unidirectional designs. But what I would like is some feedback on those design choices. Like, what is good design in certain scenarios?

Comment: Whatever design you choose, evaluate it on questions like :1) How easy it would be to add new functionality with minimal changes 2) Will you be able to reuse your code 3) Evaluate the design against SOLID princilpes